# Is it possible to show additional cabinets to a user even if it is not added in restricted_folder_ids?

Tags: documentum, webtop

I have a cabinet say "tcabinet" in a repository "trepository".
In this repository there are multiple users  however their access is restricted by adding the cabinet IDs to the restricted_folder_ids column in dm_user object.

The user has access to the ACL. But still they can not see tcabinet as their access is restricted. There are thousands of such users.

For these users to see the tcabinet. I'll have to add the object id of tcabinet to restricted_folder_ids column of each user which would definitely be a large task.

Is there any way to make them able to see the cabinet without adding the cabinet id to each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed by OpenText also, there is no other way to achive this. However we can add the cabinet to everyone's 'restricted_folder_id' attribute in dm_user table.

```
UPDATE dm_user object
APPEND restricted_folder_ids=’<Object ID of the Cabinet>’
WHERE user_name='<user_name>'
```

NOTE: If you are using this method, make sure to filter out the users which does not have any existing 'restricted_folder_id' in dm_user table, else this method will restrict the access of these users to a single folder which might not be the intention.